# Android Bottom Navigation View item title, not shown all text

Tags: android, kotlin

[image]

I want to show all of the text below the icon.Please help. Thanks

its my navigation menu xml;

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_credit_card"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_opened_credit_card_48px"
    android:title="@string/credit_or_bank_cart_payment"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_bank_transfer"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_opened_bank_transfer_48px"
    android:title="@string/bank_transfer_payment"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_cod"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_opened_cash_on_delivery_48px"
    android:title="@string/cash_on_delivery"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

Comment: where would the text be placed? There is no space

Comment: the bottom navigation view's height is wrap_content. The problem is title line is 1 . I want to title's height is be wrap_content

Comment: try `disableshiftmode`

Comment: Your item text is very large to fit on TextView. Bottom Navigation menu item title should be short to fit. Find a short term of you text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this method to make all the `BottomNavigationView`'s labels to show 2 lines:

```
private void fixBottomNavigationText(BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView) {
    for (int i = 0; i < bottomNavigationView.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View item = bottomNavigationView.getChildAt(i);

        if (item instanceof BottomNavigationMenuView) {
            BottomNavigationMenuView menu = (BottomNavigationMenuView) item;

            for (int j = 0; j < menu.getChildCount(); j++) {
                View menuItem = menu.getChildAt(j);

                View small = menuItem.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.smallLabel);
                if (small instanceof TextView) {
                    ((TextView) small).setLines(2);
                }
                View large = menuItem.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.largeLabel);
                if (large instanceof TextView) {
                    ((TextView) large).setLines(2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and call it by:

```
fixBottomNavigationText(bottomNavigationView);
```

change `bottomNavigationView` to the id of your `BottomNavigationView`.  
It is in Java and if you have trouble writing it in Kotlin let me know.  
**Edit** In Kotlin:

```
fun fixBottomNavigationText(bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView) {
    for (i in 0 until bottomNavigationView.getChildCount()) {
        val item = bottomNavigationView.getChildAt(i)

        if (item is BottomNavigationMenuView) {
            val menu = item as BottomNavigationMenuView

            for (j in 0 until menu.getChildCount()) {
                val menuItem = menu.getChildAt(j)

                val small: View = menuItem.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.smallLabel)
                if (small is TextView) {
                    (small as TextView).setLines(2)
                }
                val large: View = menuItem.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.largeLabel)
                if (large is TextView) {
                    (large as TextView).setLines(2)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```